# MySQL JOIN + SUBQUERY

Tags: php, mysql, database, join, subquery

With the following query:

```
SELECT p.*,  i.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(pc.category_id)) AS post_categories, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(pt.tag_id)) AS post_tags 
FROM posts AS p 
LEFT JOIN images AS i ON p.post_image = i.image_id 
LEFT JOIN post_categories AS pc ON p.post_id = pc.post_id 
LEFT JOIN post_tags AS pt ON p.post_id = pt.post_id 
WHERE p.post_url="'.$id.'"
```

I'm returning a list of blog posts, retrieving:

1. every column from the posts table
2. every column from the images table (for the post image)
3. a concatenation of all `category_id`'s (for the post)
4. a concatenation of all `tag_id`'s (for the post)

What this leaves me with, are two fields that aren't really helpful:

- the concatenated category_id string (i.e. "1,3")
- and the concatenated tag_id string (i.e. "2,5,8")

I would really like to do a subquery within both of the `LEFT JOINS` that allows me to, instead, return a list of:

- `category_name`'s (i.e. "meditation,sports")
- `tag_name`'s (i.e. "iOS,PHP,MySQL")

for each post.

I'm stuck right now on the subquery for both categories, and tags.

The table structures:

---

**posts**

post_id, post_title, etc.

---

**categories**

category_id, category_name

---

**tags**

tag_id, tag_name

---

**post_categories**

post_id, category_id

---

**post_tags**

post_id, tag_id

---

The question: is it possible to do such a thing effectively, if so, how?

If not, should I just store `SELECT * FROM categories` in a `$categories` array, then compare each `category_id` in the `$categories` array to each post's exploded `category_id` string in the `$posts` array each time?

Comment: Apologies, I was just being an idiot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to join to the *tags* and *categories* table, then just replace your concatenation with the name fields.  (Also have to add **Distinct** to the select so as to not return duplicated main rows.)

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*,  i.*, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(c.category_name)) AS post_categories,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(t.tag_name)) AS post_tags 
FROM posts AS p 
    LEFT JOIN images AS i ON p.post_image = i.image_id 
    LEFT JOIN post_categories AS pc ON p.post_id = pc.post_id 
    LEFT JOIN post_tags AS pt ON p.post_id = pt.post_id 
    LEFT JOIN categories AS c ON pc.category_id = c.category_id
    LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON pt.tag_id = t.tag_id
WHERE p.post_url="'.$_GET['id'].'"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've just been staring at this for too long and trying to make it more complicated than it is! lol

Comment: p.s. if you could edit `LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON pc.tag_id = t.tag_id` to say `LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON pt.tag_id = t.tag_id` that would be great. I've recently lost my editing privileges! :/

Comment: @MatisseVerDuyn ha, I think I know the feeling.  (updated the query)

Answer (score 1):

Then why not just grab the respective category name and tags description instead of their IDs in your GROUP_CONCAT